# Error when installing gems Windows 8

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I'm having the following error after installing ruby on Windows 8, I've already uninstalled it several times, fired commands like gem cleanup, removed .gem folder, ruby folder, environment variables, btut nothing seems to work.

Here are the logs of the errors I am encountering

```
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\david>gem update
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/lates
t_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Users\david>gem install compass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/lates
t_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Users\david>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-06 patchlevel 385) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/david/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

C:\Users\david>gem -v
1.8.24

C:\Users\david>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\david>
```

Comment: Does ping rubygems.org work ?

Comment: No it doesn't shows Request time out.

Comment: gem update --system did solve it. Thanks anyway.